# Converting Javascript Date object to Java LocalDateTime

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to get a UTC time from a Javascript front end to a Java backend. I wanted to accomplish this by using `Date.toISOString()` and sending that object to the Java backend. However, an issue I noticed is that `toISOString()` returns the timestamp in `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` format, and this format does not match any of the Java 8 pre-defined `LocalDateTime` formatters.

My question is, is there a best practice to do what I'm trying to do? I'm aware I can write a custom Java formatter to match the Javascript output. However, I wondered if there was a standard way to accomplish this as it seems like a very common case.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` in which time zone? If server time zone, use `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(dateString), ZoneId.systemDefault())` --- Are you *sure* you want a **local** date/time?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use on the Java side. Your ISO string defines a point in time. `LocalDateTime` cannot represent that. Use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are default ISO date formatters available. You can use following

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

Note that this will assume the LocalDateTime of UTC timezone.

**Update**: as per Andreas' comment.

If you wish to get instance of LocalDateTime in server timezone, use

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(str), ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Comment: That ignores the time zone, making the `LocalDateTime` be UTC in this case. How do you know OP wants the **local** date/time in UTC?

Comment: You are right, ISO_DATE_TIME does work! I was under the impression that it wouldn't because the examples provided on the Java docs were '2011-12-03T10:15:30', '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00' and '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'. I did not realize the Z was a valid zone it would detect.